# What does font size -2 mean here?

Tags: html, fonts, size

I see this from source code of a web site:

```
<font size="-2">@2009 </font>
```

What does it mean when size is negative?

Comment: Why the vote down. Its a valid question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means the font size of **@2009** should be -2 units (i.e. 2 units smaller) relative to the content around it.

Comment: When no "unit" is specified it's just a font size of 1 to 7. Honestly not sure how each browser calculates the "units" into actual font size (px/em/etc) but perhaps someone knows the equation here...

Comment: Each browser is free to interpret the relative size as it sees fit.  Some non-visual browsers may even interpret the relative font to be relative loudness of read-back.

Comment: I think they're fairly equivalent to the `small`, `medium`, `large` etc keywords from CSS, with 3 or 4 being the "medium".

Answer (score 10):

That is a deprecated style of markup. [Nobody should be using it anymore](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_FONT.asp).

Back in the old days, before CSS, you could use the `<font>` tag to control the relative size of text on the page.  A "-2" simply meant two sizes smaller than your base font size.

Font sizes ranged from 1 to 7 in first generation browsers, if I recall correctly.

Comment: CSS has relative size equivalents, `smaller` and `larger`, as well as the 7 "standard" sizes, which are now referred to as `xx-small` through `xx-large`.  (Docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Syntax).)

Answer (score 0):

It means two notches smaller than the default text size in the browser.

Comment: ..."`notch`" must be a deprecated unit label that I hadn't heard of. ‎

Comment: @ashleedawg: The accepted answer uses the term "units," which is *almost* as precise.